# gnus: find recent messages from a user across many newsgroups

Tags: search, gnus

Using gnus, what is the best way to find the most recent (eg 10) messages posted by a user across many newsgroups?

I am subscribed to almost 100 newsgroups and sometimes I *know* that user X has posted recently on a topic: but I can't find the post!

Ideas?